# Consult SPARQL for Wikipedia articles related to diseases

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have a SPARQL query to get from DBPedia a list of Wikipedia articles related to diseases, but the result not only gets articles related to diseases, it also gets articles that have nothing to do with them, not even in the field of health. For example:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_in_film
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Western_Australian_gas_crisis
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2003_Wimbledon_Championships_-_Women' s_Singles
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1955_Hawaiian_submarine_eruption
```

among others

My question is, is the consultation correct? Otherwise, it is a problem of how certain articles are categorized in DBPedia. This is the query:

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?d ?dn ?wikiPage ?icd9 ?icd10 ?disDB ?meshID ?mlp ?omim ?emed ?frbase 
WHERE {
    ?d a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Disease>.
    ?d foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikiPage.
    OPTIONAL { ?d <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/icd9> ?icd9. }
    OPTIONAL { ?d <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/icd10> ?icd10. }
    OPTIONAL { ?d <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/diseasesDb> ?disDB. }
    OPTIONAL { ?d <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/meshId> ?meshID. }
    OPTIONAL { ?d <http://dbpedia.org/property/medlineplus> ?mlp. }
    OPTIONAL { ?d <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/omim> ?omim. }
    OPTIONAL { ?d <http://dbpedia.org/property/emedicinetopic> ?emed.}
    OPTIONAL {
        ?d owl:sameAs ?frbase.
        FILTER(regex(str(?frbase),"freebase","i")).
    }
        OPTIONAL {
                ?d rdfs:label ?dn.
                FILTER(lang(?dn) = 'en')
        }
}
```

Comment: First your query is full of syntactic errors; spaces before question marks, non closed parentheses... Second, as I see the data might not be clean; for example a Syntax error has a rdf:type of dbo:Disease! (See http://dbpedia.org/page/Syntax_error). You might try wikidata:Q12136 instead of dbo:Disease, but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, please fix all the syntax errors, there are even triple patterns where the object var is missing sometimes. Prefix declarations are also rubbish. How did you run this query?! This can't work

Comment: And to give you an answer to your question, indeed the data in DBpedia isn't "perfect" - you can simply [click on the resources](http://dbpedia.org/page/2008_Western_Australian_gas_crisis) and see that those have been asserted to the class `dbo:disease`

Comment: Note, all of those resources don't have an infobox on Wikipedia, thus, the classification is done by some heuristics and not by infobox template mappings.

Comment: Query corrected, thanks! Do you know if there is any more accurate way to retrieve the "disease articles" that exist in Wikipedia by querying DBpedia? At the end, I would like to get a "list of all the diseases that appears in Wikipedia" and I thought that the best way was using DBpedia

Comment: Any idea to get a "list of all the diseases that appears in Wikipedia"?